# Multiple CSGO servers with each a unique IP assigning to one domain

Tags: subdomain, ubuntu-20.04, gameserver

I got some CSGO servers up and running using [LGSM](https://docs.linuxgsm.com/configuration/ip-address). I am trying to assign a sub domain (s1, s2, s3 etc.) to each gameserver but only `s1.domain.com` can be found in the Serverlist.

To achieve this each gameserver should have a unique IP address so s2 already has a different IP address in the lgsm instance cfg.

The (dedicated) server was originally configured on the IP address of s1 (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd) and also the domain DNS settings is using this one. So in the DNS I already configured an A record with the value s1 assigning to aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd. This is working fine but now I need to add a second. As far as I understand it is not possible to add a second A record with the value s2 pointing to the other unique IP address.

**S1 LGSM instance config**

```
s1.domain.com = THIS ONE DOES WORK
gslt="UNRELEVANT"
ip="aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"
port="27015"
clientport="27005"
sourcetvport="27025"
gamemode="2"
gametype="1"
```

**S1 LGSM instance details ([LGSM](https://docs.linuxgsm.com/configuration/ip-address) `./<instancename> details`)**

```
Server IP:        aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:27016
Master server:    Listed
Status:           ONLINE
```

**S2 LGSM instance config**

```
s2.domain.com
gslt="UNRELEVANT"
ip="www.xxx.yyy.zzz"
port="27016"
clientport="27006"
sourcetvport="27026"
gamemode="2"
gametype="1"
```

**S2 instance details ([LGSM](https://docs.linuxgsm.com/configuration/ip-address) `./<instancename> details`)**

```
Server IP:        www.xxx.yyy.zzz:27016
Internet IP:      aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:27016
Master server:    not listed
Status:           ONLINE
```

**The servers *do* listen on right IP:**

```sh
# sudo ss -plunt
tcp LISTEN 0 2 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:27015 0.0.0.0:* users:(("srcds_linux",pid=696741,fd=26))
tcp LISTEN 0 2 www.xxx.yyy.zzz:27016 0.0.0.0:* users:(("srcds_linux",pid=712565,fd=26))
```

*I also find it weird that the command for s2 shows an extra "Internet IP" line. Is this the issue? Does this also explain why the master server is NOT LISTED? When I change the IP address to the original one (aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd) with port 27016 (instead of s1's 27015) the server WILL BE listed and can be found*

**How can I configure that s1.domain.com will find server aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd and s2.domain.com [www.xxx.yyy.zzz](http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz)**

Comment: LGSM (Linux Game Server Managers) has a command called "./<instancename> details". The details of the second server (s2) shows an Internet IP (https://docs.linuxgsm.com/configuration/ip-address)

Comment: You can probably use the output of `sudo ss -plunt` to clarify which server is bound to which IP.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning which release (version) of that utility you are using.

Comment: sudo ss -plunt output;
tcp       LISTEN     0          2                                   aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:27015                0.0.0.0:*         users:(("srcds_linux",pid=696741,fd=26))

tcp       LISTEN     0          2                                  www.xxx.yyy.zzz:27016               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("srcds_linux",pid=712565,fd=26)) 

So the servers do have the right IP I guess?

Comment: can you tell us hie this might be a business related question?